# How to Unit test a method in java which has asynchronous calls in it using Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, java-8, concurrency, mockito

I have below class in which a method has CompletableFuture.supplyAsync call and returns CompleteableFuture
How can I unit test this method? Please check below for more details

```
public class ServiceA {

    private final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;
    private final ClassA objA;
    private final ClassB objB;


    public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity> methodA(Object obj,  int number) {

        validating(obj)

        someProcessing(obj, userId);


        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() ->
                                       objA.getData(num,obj), taskExecutor)
                        .thenApply(response -> convertToSomething(response,obj))
                        .thenAccept(response -> objB.doSomeThing(response,
                                                                          arg)))
                        .exceptionally(throwable -> {

                            return null;
                        })
                        .thenAccept(val -> ResponseEntity.ok().build())
                        .join();

        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(ResponseEntity.ok()
                                                               .build());
    }
  }
```

I have to unit test methodA. Can someone help me out?
Thanks In Advance

Comment: I presume you're using `CompletableFuture` here in order to introduce some concurrency. However, note that your call to `join()` negates that entirely. The thread calling your method now waits for the future to complete before continuing, meaning your method is effectively synchronous.

Comment: I was given this code and asked to write test case for this. Is there a way I can unit test this?

Comment: If you're testing the result just get the result from the `CompletableFuture` (e.g. by calling `join()`). Then you just create a unit test like any other. You may want to inject a mock thread pool, however, so that you don't create threads in your unit test. Of course, that would have been much easier if `taskExecutor` was an `ExecutorService`(i.e. the interface) and not a `ThreadPoolExecutor` (i.e. the implementation). This is one of those cases showing why programming to an interface is often preferable.